# add to watch versus add to quick watch

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Are there any differences between add to watch and add to quick watch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Add to watch" adds the variable to the Watch window, so that you can see its value changing as you step through the code.

"QuickWatch" pops up a transient dialog showing the value, without permanently adding it anyhere.  When you close that dialog, you can no longer see the value.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Richie's answer.

In terms of what they can and cannot evaluate there is no difference.  Under the hood they use the same evaluation techniques and can represent an equivalent set of expressions.