# Memorystream.Read() always returns 0 bytesRead with empty byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I currently have a [memorystream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.MemoryStream(v=vs.110).aspx) with length of about `30000` (`Named memStream here`)
I wished to [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.read(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) this memorystream in `chunks` using the following code (I picked up on the net and modified somewhat):

```
        byte[] chunk = new byte[4096];
        bool hasNext = true;

        while(hasNext)
        {
            int index = 0;

            while (index < chunk.Length)
            {
                int bytesRead = memStream.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                index += bytesRead;
                //Do something with this chunk
            }
            if (index != 0) // Our previous chunk may have been the last one
            {
                //Do something with the last chunk
            }
            if (index != chunk.Length) // We didn't read a full chunk: we're done
            {
                hasNext = false;
            }
        }
```

yet the following `read()`method doesn't appear to be working

```
  int bytesRead = memStream.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);

  WHERE
    chunk: new byte[4096]
    index: 0
    memstream: capacitiy & length : 34272
    memstream: position 0 (according to VS watch)

 Always returns
    0 bytesRead
    Chunk with all values containing '0'
```

Any idea why? Could this be a rights permission?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you reset the position of the stream after filling it?

Comment: @leppie no I didn't. but looking at the properties of the memorystream, the `position is 0`. But i'll try again with explicity saying the starting position should be `0`

Comment: Good, was just checking as that is a common point of failure :) Check the `Length` property too to ensure there is actual data.

Comment: Your description is in error somewhere. I would say most likely the `Position`, as suggested by leppie. `Stream.Read()` returns 0 if and only if you are at the end of the stream (or you actually asked to read 0 bytes). So whatever you _think_ is the case, you're probably at the end of the stream. If you post a good, complete, concise code example, we can even tell you exactly why.

Comment: @leppie You were right. `I explicity set the position to '0'` and now  it appears to be working. `odd`, but the watch (on my `memstream`) must have been showing somehow the wrong data.

Comment: Watches on properties do not refresh automatically IIRC.

Comment: Aha found a usefull post here on StackOverflow: [Watch vs Quick Watch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466989/add-to-watch-versus-add-to-quick-watch) Seeing as I was using a quick watch its starting to make more sense

Comment: Can you show us how you are loading you memStream?  I set your code up and places values in s memstream and I am getting values back.

Comment: @LawrenceThurman Leppie solved it for me. The position was actually not 0. The quickwatch didn't adequatly refresh the data. Setting the position explitictly to 0 just before the `while`did solve it for me. Or in other words: `You shall not blindy trust quickwatch`. Thanx for the interest though

Answer (score 12):

After creating and filling the MemoryStream, you need to set the read position to the begining like so:

```
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```