# Return File from URL as IActionResult

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I am attempting to get a PDF to download upon the press of a button using .Net Core and Razor Pages. This is as close as I've gotten but am encountering the error

> "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
> System.IO.FileStream.ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)".

How do I properly return the file?

Test.cshtml

```
@page
@model LoanCalculator.Pages.TestModel
@{
}
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Test.cshtml.cs

```
namespace LoanCalculator.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/a2p-v2-storage/528a02ea-a399-4901-b8d6-d0494be68331";
        byte[] imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

        using var fs = new FileStream("favicon.png", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        return File(fs, "application/pdf", "FileDownloadName.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882038/memorystream-read-always-returns-0-bytesread-with-empty-byte as you must reset the read position in the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are disposing the stream and not setting the position of the stream to zero.

You can make this much more memory efficient by just handing the stream off from the request to the response.

Take a look at this example:

```
var targetFile = new Uri("https://www.example.com/file.pdf");

var resp = await _httpClientFactory.CreateClient().GetAsync(
    targetFile, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

Response.ContentLength = resp.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

return File(await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
    "application/pdf", Path.GetFileName(targetFile.LocalPath));
```

*(this is not tested and written from memory)*

Also, you should be using `IHttpClientFactory` and not create a new `HttpClient` each time.

An example of this:

```cs
// ...
using System.Net.Http;
// ...

namespace LoanCalculator.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public TestModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Startup.cs`, add this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddHttpClient();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Newbie question - "_httpClientFactory does not exist in the current context", any advice for creating it?

Comment: @MaxPowers -- updated the answer to show how to inject an HttpClient factory.

Comment: Thank you. There is another error with the code at targetFile.Url.LocalPath, "CS1061: 'Uri' does not contain a definition for 'Url' and no accessible extension method 'Url' accepting a first argument of type 'Uri' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" The show potential fixes doesn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: @MaxPowers -- I mistyped -- updated answer. It should be `targetFile.LocalPath`

Comment: Looks great except still working through issues with adding the HttpClient factory.

Comment: @MaxPowers -- What's the issue? I did have a typo in where the private variable was placed. Make sure it's in class scope. I added the namespace that needs to be added to the top of your file.

Comment: Just needed a minute to properly apply it, got it now, I think. I notice there is no file extension when the file is downloaded but neither does the url, looking into that now.

Comment: @MaxPowers -- oh yeah, there wouldn't be. Just replace `Path.GetFileName(targetFile.LocalPath)` with anything you'd like.. for example `"File.pdf"`. The URL you are downloading doesn't have a file name. That's why it's blank. I didn't see that.

Comment: Yup, got through that and works like a charm. You literally saved me man, got a killer deadline and this was the bottleneck. I'm mostly a SQL shredder so a fish out of water here. Thank you!