# How to convert wave stereo file to mono and return it as blob using NAudio

Tags: c#, json, naudio

I am using below code to convert Wave stereo to mono file using Naudio.

```cs
try
{
    // convert our stereo ISampleProvider to mono
    var mono = new StereoToMonoSampleProvider(inputReader)
    {
        LeftVolume = 1.0f, // if discard the left channel keep  0.0f
        RightVolume = 1.0f // keep the right  channel
    };
    var root = _config.GetValue<string>("DownloadPath");
    if (!Directory.Exists(root))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
    }
    string tempFile = Path.Combine(root, $"MonoFile-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff}.wav");
    _logger.LogInformation(tempFile, "file location");
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(tempFile, mono);
    _logger.LogInformation("Write Mono File Successful");
}
```

can anyone help to how to return converted file as blob

Comment: What's a JSON blob?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036849/1204153). It shows how to return binary data as a `File` object.